How to grep the keywords in two different file
Below two scripts starts at same timestamp but I want to differentiate the output filename for logging purpose. Once output is created then we need to search the specific keyword in two different output files.
Shell script 1
Test1=`command 2>output.txt`

Shell script 2
Test1=`command 2>output.txt`

Shell script 3 and so on


What is your actual goal?  I suspect there is some followon processing of the outputs; what does that do?  I suspect there is a global architecture change that could greatly simplify your process.

How about using the process-id?
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME="output-$(date +%C%y%m%d%H%M%s)-$$.txt"
comannd 2>"${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}"
grep "stuff to look for" "${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}"


Thanks. But how do i use the above created file name to grep the keyword

Do you want to grep from inside the script generating the output while also saving the entire output?

I need to grep the keyword in the above file mentioned after test 1 command completes which saves the output of the command in the above file

Ok.  I will add that to my answer, but please add that clarification to the question.


how do i differentiate the output.tx

You can't.
You have to change the source of the log lines - add unique elements to each log line, split it to multiple files, etc.
I see other answers show particular solutions, I like test1 | logger -t test1, because I do not have to care about log rotation of journalctl log files, they never fill my disc to maximum, are nicely compressed, and I can centralize all in one place.

Thanks. I will find out and try passing the unique in the script to create separate output file.

What do you mean by "people below"?  Are you assuming a particular ordering of answers?

@TobySpeight yes I am

I would do something like this:
In the first script:
 command 2>&1 >/dev/tty | sed 's/^/script1:/' >output1.txt

In the second:
 command 2>&1 >/dev/tty | sed 's/^/script2:/' >output2.txt

and so on.  You can send stdout wherever, of course, but /dev/tty keeps it going to the terminal even while you're piping stderr on through to your log.

Thank you. Let me try this and come back.
